# Can we rotate the digital crown in Apple Watch simulator without having a mouse- or trackpad?

Tags: ios-simulator, watchos-2, trackpad

The only reference I can find in operating (rotating/turning) the digital crown on the Apple Watch 2.0 / 3.x simulator is by using a track/mouse-pad.
Is it possible with a mighty mouse to rotate/turn the digital crown in a simulator?

Answer (score 25):

Any pointing device with a scroll capability will work, whether that is a gesture or a physical scroll wheel.

Position the pointer inside the crown button area then perform the scroll gesture.

edit: By popular demand, Xcode 11 allows you to perform the scroll gesture anywhere within the watch window to scroll the digital crown.

Comment: I tested it on a MacMini with MacOS-Sierra, the latest Xcode and an AppleMouse 1st generation (the first AppleTouch-mouse) but this definitely doesn't work. It does however work with an AppleMouse 2nd generation on a MacBookPro with MacOS-HighSierra and the latest Xcode.
So 'any pointing device with a scroll capability' will most probably only work on the latest MacOS I guess?

Comment: It is intended to work. Can you file a bug on this and send me the #?